# How can I stop a method while it is performing its function with a set on click listener?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop, conditional-statements

> what code should I write here to stop the following method while it is running the state?
>   the following method turns the flashlight on and off, I want to stop this method when I press "stop flash button".

```
     private void BlinkFlash(){

          blinks=true;
       while (blinks=true)
        {
                params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.startPreview();


                try {
                Thread.sleep(1);

                    params = camera.getParameters();
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    camera.stopPreview();

            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }


        }
```

Comment: The easiest way would to have both of them synchronize on some object, and set a boolean inside the OnClickListener which the loop in the other function looks at.

Comment: Hi  Michael, take a look at it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For async functions you should use AtomicBoolean.
Example of code:

```
AtomicBoolean shouldContinue = new AtomicBoolean(true);
private void BlinkFlash(){

   shouldContinue.set(true);

   while (shouldContinue.get())
    {
           ....
    }
}



private void stopFlash(){
 shouldContinue.set(false);
}
```